# Run python code from stdin with additional script arguments in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, pipeline

The use case is the following:

1. convert jupyter notebook to python
2. run converted notebook on-the fly with additional arguments

What I have tried so far:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to python --stdout .\some_nb.ipynb | python
```

`some_nb.ipynb` awaits for arguments via `argparse` so normally I would do something like:

```sh
python some_nb.py --argument_one=1
```

When I do that:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to python --stdout .\some_nb.ipynb | python --argument_one=1
```

`argument_one` is of course binded to `python` and I am not sure how to properly pipeline this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it. Python has `-` argument after which it reads arguments from stdin

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python --stdout .\some_nb.ipynb| python - --argument_one=1
```